# Undefined function 'priview' for input arguments of type 'videoinput'

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a program in matlab for opening camera.
This is my code:

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
vid = videoinput('winvideo',1);
priview(vid);
```

I am getting

```
Undefined function 'priview' for input arguments of type 'videoinput'
```

this error.

Comment: It's "`preview`", with an 'e', isn't it?

Comment: @LuisMendo I've edited his question.

Comment: @KashishArora: Please don't fix typographic errors in code or error messages. The problem is the typographic error, if you fix it the cause of the error is hidden.

Comment: @Daniel, Oh! Okay. I'm sorry!

Answer (score 2):

There is no `priview()`, you are looking for [**`preview()`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/preview.html).

So change `priview(vid);` to `preview(vid);`.